# How to get cookies stored by javascript?

Tags: python, web-crawler, mechanize

I am using mechanize to retrieve data from many web site. When I tried to log into www.douban.com , I found there are a lot of cookies not set when I log in success. Finally, I find they came from google analytics. They were set by javascript. However, [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html#script) can not handle javascript, so how to get these cookies. Without these cookies I still can not visit www.douban.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) is a headless webkit-based client supporting all bells and wisthles, JavaScript included. It had Python API (PyPhantomJS) which was unfortunately removed due to lack of maintainer. You may still want to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that, but unless Your crawler knows how to run Javascript code, You are unable to fetch cookies set by Javascript.